# Error: "The table or data volume was larger than BI Engine supports at this time"

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

Trying to use BI Engine with a BigQuery table and Data Studio. I get the error "The table or data volume was larger than BI Engine supports at this time". My table is partitioned, what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to tell Data Studio to use the partitioned column!

If Data Studio shows a table is not accelerated with an error like this:

[image]

Then go to data source definition, and make sure to tell it to use the partitioning column as a partitioning column:

```
Partitioned Table
Use <column name> as partitioning column
```

[image]

Now Data Studio shows the dashboard being accelerated:

[image]

Track developments for this issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140507651.

Comment: Where do you configure the partition column?