# Why BigQuery BI engine does not use all the reservation?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-bi-engine

I have a dashboard connected to a BigQuery Table, BI engine works as expected as I am using a calendar filter and my table is partitioned per date.
when I select a longer date range, BI engine stop working with this message "The table or data volume was larger than BI Engine supports at this time", that's fair.

Please notice, I am already filtering by a partition, but sometimes, I need to see the whole data

to solve that, I created a BI reservation, and I notice regardless of the size 1,2,4 GB the memory used is always 600MB? and I get the same message, I attached a screenshot here, is this by design?

[image]

Bug Report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150633500

Comment: Try the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58276712/132438

Comment: of course i tried, I reported that Bug a couple of months ago :)

Answer (score 1):

turn out the error is not related to reservation, but to the fact that BI engine support only 500 partition, my table has more

https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/overview#limitations

the solution is instead of partition per day, I will use something like week or month